# Why is it not possible to access a page I host on a device on the same network by way of it's domain?

Tags: nginx, networking, ip, reverse-proxy

First I want to apologize for the title of the question, SO now requires an impossible title format

Anyway,

**TL;DR**
Is there anything I can do to make my laptop ignore the fact that raspberry pi, which serves a website on a example.co.uk domain, is on the same network w.r.t the address bar?

**Why?**
I have a raspberry pi, running nginx as a reverse proxy, serving only a static index.html file for testing purposes. The external IP address for this is xxx.yyy.z.32 and it's on port 80 (again, for testing purposes)

I have a domain name, example.com, hosted on GoDaddy, pointing to xxx.yyy.z.32

On my Zhone router I've opened external port 80 and pointed it to internal port 80

On my phone, which is connected to the internet via 4G, I can visit example.com and it loads fine

On my laptop, on the same network as the raspberry pi, I cannot access example.com, as is custom

My problem is, that I need to be able to enter example.com into the address bar, because in reality I need to be able to enter sub domains such as redmine.example.com, because I am hosting multiple services, and I need to be able to check if everything is working fine on my laptop, where most of my work get's done

**Extra info**

- All devices are running linux except the phone.
- Everything on the raspberry is in a docker container on the same docker network

Comment: The problem is the router cannot route the connection using the public IP address when both client and server are behind the same NAT. One solution is a private DNS server on the LAN which gives your WiFi clients the internal address for `*.example.com`.

Comment: @RichardSmith That sounds cool, maybe I'll give that a try